# EF Core 2.2 runs SELECT * FROM [TableName] with no SELECT query in my code

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.2

I have the following pieces of code:

```
public class BaseEntity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset CreatedDate { get; set; }
    [Timestamp]
    public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
}

public class StateHistory : BaseEntity
{
    public string RegistrationFlowTitle { get; set; }
    public string RegistrationStateTitle { get; set; }
    public Guid? PartyId { get; set; }      
}

public class Party : BaseEntity {
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

//StateHistoryRepository.cs
public class StateHistoryRepository : BaseRepository<StateHistory>, IStateHistoryRepository
{
    public StateHistoryRepository(DbContext context) : base(context)
    { }

    public void Add(StateHistory history)
    {
        Context.StateHistories.Add(history);
    }

    public async Task AddAsync(StateHistory history)
    {
        await Context.StateHistories.AddAsync(history);
    }
}

//PartyService.cs
public async Task<ServiceResponse> UpdatePartyAsync(Party model)
{
    var existingParty = await _partyRepository.GetParty(model.Id, asNoTracking:false);
    if (existingParty == null)
    {
        return ServiceResponse<ServiceResponse>.Failed(message: "");
    }

    existingParty.FirstName = model.FirstName;
    existingParty.LastName = model.LastName;


    await _stateHistoryRepository.AddAsync(new StateHistory{RegistrationFlowTitle = "RegistrationFlowTitle", RegistrationStateTitle = "RegistrationStateTitle", 
        PartyId = model.Id});

    await _partyRepository.CommitAsync();
    return ServiceResponse.Successful();
}
```

All my project is designed as above. But in some scenarios that I have no idea about, when running the SQL Server Profiler, I see the following query:

```
SELECT [s].[Id], [s].[CreatedDate], [s].[PartyId], [s].[RegistrationFlowTitle], [s].[RegistrationStateTitle], [s].[RowVersion] FROM [StateHistories] AS [s]
```

How is it possible when I have not `SELECT` query on `StateHistorie` table, but it runs in the background? Is it a bug from EF Core? How can I track it? Since the table has over 5 million records, it creates deadlocks in database!

Comment: Are you using a logging framework?

Comment: I am using serilog to log into Elasticsearch

Comment: Does migration make such a `SELECT` statement? If yes, why?

Comment: Maybe this: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/15214 ?

Comment: Thanks a million. It did work